# How to set Azure Max Spending Limit or Cost CAP $ amount?

Tags: azure

I'm now using a free trial Azure account.

I have a question that when I convert into a subscription after free trial,
How to set a max spending limit $ amount or Spending CAP, for example 10$ per day or 200$ per month?
If it reach this max $ amount, it can just automatically shut off or temporary disable my site in order to prevent some evil attack or unexpected usage to my Azure sites causing a large charge billing of my Credit Card.

Nowadays azure only support free trial Spending Limit to 0$ and cannot change this 0$ amount to other $ amount:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/spending-limits/

I have raised a request to the Azure Support, and get a reply that they have no information whether this feature will be available in the future.
And I searched a lot, there are many people concern this problem too:

[Can I set a cap on costs in Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733066/can-i-set-a-cap-on-costs-in-windows-azure)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/windowsazurepurchasing/thread/abfd03c5-2173-4762-9dd1-2aab802e0890

http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/170023-offers/suggestions/1024115-provide-a-way-to-put-a-limit-on-the-cost-of-a-serv

Is this feauture in the roadmap of Azure development?

Is it possiable to set a max spending limit $amount of my VISA Credit Card at the bank?

For example, if my Credit Card limits itself a max spending $amount, can Azure charge me exceed the Credit Card'limit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Azure subscription comes with certain capacity depend on subscription type. For example  free subscriptions have limited resources and going beyond resources limit the subscription will be disabled. With regular subscription you have limited cores (you can request them to a higher limit) but most of other resources are open for as much as you can use. There are certain limitation on SQL Database, Cache, Services Bus & ACS depend on account limit you have selected.

Currently there is no way you can setup capacity limit on Windows Azure Account. You can not set Windows Azure to use under or equal X amount. About new features and future plans are not something can be discussed in a forum. Such kind of information is made public when it is appropriate to share as if needed. If this is something important for you and you want to be added as feature, you can log your idea [here](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting) and your voice will be heard.

Comment: Is this answer still valid ?

Comment: This is from january 2014: http://blog.zebsadiq.com/post/Azure-Spending-limit-not-currently-available-on-pay-as-you-go.aspx ["The spending limit feature is only available for certain kinds of accounts "]

Comment: Absolutely right because of that we wrote our own tool to control the different spending limits for the different departments. As we learned there are more people having the same problem we opened it for everybody: https://azure-costs.com

Comment: Here are some links from Microsoft about this topic: [We don't have custom spend limits today](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-spending-limit) However, you can opt in to [use billing alerts to control your spend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-set-up-alerts).

Comment: Billing alerts are the same garbage that AWS has. For some reason I thought Microsoft was more in-tune with developers than this rather than generating $$$

Comment: Feel free to rage here:
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a962ca12-2c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f84

Answer (score 11):

The subscriptions that support spending limits are listed [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/).  Adding limits to pay-as-you-go subscriptions is [planned](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906772-cost-management/suggestions/3238796-spending-limit-or-maximum-cost-cap-for-azure), but there hasn't been an update for several years.

Comment: 5 years on and still no update on adding limits to pay-as-you-go subscriptions!

Comment: 6 years and this feature is not yet active

Comment: 7 + years. Answer hasn't changed

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to create a budget inside Azure, whereby you can get an email if the costs get to e.g. 90% of your the amount you want to spend pr. month. This way you can manually shut down services inside Azure. Just go to Azue portal > Cost Management + Billing > Budget > Add > fill in relevant info.

Comment: as of today this is not possible on pay-as-you-go subs

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with this "free" tier (both AWS and Azure) is that you must be always checking if you shut on/off your services, and if you fail one day, or if you are sleeping, on holiday, travelling, if your latpot just gets out of battery... A simple DDOS attack or the fact of reaching the limit just in the moment can generate for you costs for +400$ in a few days. Microsoft and AWS support must be really tired of checking tickets about that undesired costs, defaults, etc, etc, you ALWAYS are suitable for getting charges, the name "free" is a false friend.

A trick that works for me is registering a credit card for payment and then cancelling it. So if undesired costs are generated, they can not just get the money. It worked for me few months ago, I talked with support and they cancelled costs in about 2 weeks, and no money were taked from my account at any moment.