# Windows Azure payment

Tags: azure, payment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set Azure Max Spending Limit or Cost CAP $ amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787789/how-to-set-azure-max-spending-limit-or-cost-cap-amount)

I have account with "Windows Azure para Visual Studio Ultimate com MSDN", is possible to enable a limit after free services?
Example I wanto no use more than $400/month? When execeed from free amount...

Comment: I guess this post answers your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787789/how-to-set-azure-max-spending-limit-or-cost-cap-amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot re-enable monthly spending limits on Azure:

> You can remove the Spending Limit at any time. However, once removed,
>   the Spending Limit feature cannot be re-enable

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/spending-limits/