# Quotas on Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I just have a small question to ask. Can I set quotas on my usage of Windows Azure? I did look through the azure documentation, but maybe it slipped me.

Answer (score 1):

YOu cant set a monetary spending limit - quotas depend on your subscription type - see this answer,

[How to set Azure Max Spending Limit or Cost CAP $ amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787789/how-to-set-azure-max-spending-limit-or-cost-cap-amount)