# Azure functions set hard limit to free tier

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm interested in using Azure Functions for a piece of serverless code, but I would like to ensure that I am *always* within the free tier, so as to not incur any expenses (I'm okay with potential downtime, not really critical). How do I achieve this?

My function is limited to some domains I control, and possibly a resource used in GitHub readme (like a tracking pixel). How do I combat potential DDOS, and massive bill spikes?

I've seen other questions on how to manage fanout, scale etc, but none on setting hard limits. I'm still a student, so I'd rather stay exclusively in the free tier.

Note, by 'Free tier', I mean the 'Always Free' offering.

Comment: Relevant question for many IMO, I had touched on this topic in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68475227/5362795) I later deleted. It linked a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12787789/5362795) specific to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannont (as far as I know) set a hard limit.

What you can do is to reduce your functions ability to scale. So that it can just process a single request at a time, then depending on how long the request takes you will stay within the free tier.

https://nullable.online/2018/11/20/how-to-throttle-a-azure-function-hosted-on-a-consumption-plan/

Comment: Yeah already went through the article you linked. Bummer that I can't set a hard limit :/ . I guess I'll have to calculate how long it takes to process my request, and then set the limits accordingly.